# Appengine and JPA - Read data that has just been written

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa-2.0, google-cloud-datastore

I'm just getting started on AppEngine but have some issues with the datastore.

I want to use JPA to write some data to the datastore. I have been following the Java examples from the Appengine website with the guestbook example and I wanted to translate this guestbook example to use JPA 2.0.

When I run the application with some data already available in my datastore (created using previous runs) in my output it shows me that I have 7 items before writing, then the writing is ok, afterwards it again gives me 7 items. But if I open my admin-console (http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore?kind=Greeting) I can see that I have already 8 items in the datastore. So for some reason I'm suffering phantom reads...

All my code is shown below.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is how my persistence.xml looks like:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And this is the code:

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = EMF.get();
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            // Reading the data
            javax.persistence.Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT FROM Greeting g");
            List<Greeting> greetings = query.getResultList();
            for (Greeting g : greetings) {
                log.info("Greeting found: " + g.getContent());
            }
            log.info("Number of greetings found before writing: " + greetings.size());

            // Storing the data
            Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
            greeting.setUser(user);
            greeting.setDate(new Date());
            greeting.setContent(content);

            em.persist(greeting);
            em.flush();

            // Reading the data
            query = em.createQuery("SELECT FROM Greeting g");
            greetings = query.getResultList();
            for (Greeting g : greetings) {
                log.info("Greeting found: " + g.getContent());
            }
            log.info("Number of greetings found after writing: " + greetings.size());
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warning("Cannot write to database because of error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google AppEngine doesn't support that kind of database consistency. Instead of replicating the DB in the background, for every write, they simultaneously write to > 50% of the copies and finish the replication later. So if you write, then immediately read, your read might hit a copy that has not been replicated yet.

You just have to change your code to avoid read after write. Normally this shouldn't be a problem because it is already in memory.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

To change that setting in Eclipse, go to Project > Right Click > Google > AppEngine Settings >  Run Configurations > Web Application > YOUR PROJECT > App Engine > High Replication Settings (HRD) Unapplied Job Percentage > 50. This value emulates the % of times a read will fail after a write in development. 0% = normal database (but will fail in production).

JPA sits on top of Datastore API, so it suffers the same problem.